# What is the css property for showing the ... when there is overflow-x?

Tags: css

The property `overflow-x` shows scrollbar when the content exceeds the parent's width. I do not want to show the scrollbar but instead show the three dots "..." How to achieve that ?

Comment: Does it only contains text?

Comment: it is a tree , so there may be also images

Comment: Did it also work for images? i thought it works only for text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

This will only apply with text.

[MDN - text-overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

> This property only affects content that is overflowing a block
>   container element in its inline progression direction (not text
>   overflowing at the bottom of a box, for example). Text can overflow
>   when it is prevented from wrapping (e.g., due to ‘white-space:
>   nowrap’) or a single word being too long to fit.

```css
.truncate {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="truncate">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br>
Anim consequat. magna in et ullamco laborum. qui ea laboris non dolore anim nulla dolor irure sint Excepteur do esse in nostrud consectetur tempor Excepteur ullamco proident, ut enim tempor laboris enim eiusmod exercitation ut sed anim Excepteur dolor enim elit, mollit minim culpa consectetur cupidatat consectetur magna commodo in ut sed eu irure amet, Ut Ut Lorem Excepteur occaecat eiusmod ut ipsum in.
</div>
```

If you need a working solution that applies to anything other than text, you may need to consider javascript.